# How can I do relative imports in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Imagine this directory structure:

```
app/
   __init__.py
   sub1/
      __init__.py
      mod1.py
   sub2/
      __init__.py
      mod2.py
```

I'm coding `mod1`, and I need to import something from `mod2`. How should I do it?

I tried `from ..sub2 import mod2`, but I'm getting an "Attempted relative import in non-package".

I googled around, but I found only "`sys.path` manipulation" hacks. Isn't there a clean way?

---

All my `__init__.py`'s are currently empty

I'm trying to do this because sub2 contains classes that are shared across sub packages (`sub1`, `subX`, etc.).

The behaviour I'm looking for is the same as described in [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) ([thanks John B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python#comment8465_72852)).

Comment: I recommend updating your question to make it more clear that you're describing the issue addressed in PEP 366.

Comment: It's a long winded explanation but check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10713254/1267156 I answered a very similar question. I had this same problem until last night.

Comment: For those who wish to load a module located at an arbitrary path, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: On a related note, Python 3 will change the default handling of imports to be absolute by default; relative imports will have to be explicitly specified.

Answer (score 384, accepted):

The problem is that you're running the module as '__main__' by passing the mod1.py as an argument to the interpreter.

From [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/):

> Relative imports use a module's __name__ attribute to determine that module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to '__main__') then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file system.

In Python 2.6, they're adding the ability to reference modules relative to the main module.  [PEP 366](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) describes the change.

Comment: The answer here involves messing with sys.path at every entry point to your program.  I guess that's the only way to do it.

Comment: The recommended alternative is to run modules inside packages using the `-m` switch, rather than by specifying their filename directly.

Comment: I don't understand: where is the answer here? How can one import modules in such a directory structure?

Comment: @Tom: In this instance, mod1 would `from sub2 import mod2`.  Then, to run mod1, from within app, do `python -m sub1.mod1`.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov: does this mean you can't do it if your python is embedded in an application, so you don't have access to python command line switches?

Comment: @MattJoiner: It works if you run mod1.py as `python -m app.sub1.mod1` (from the parent dir of `app`) as [Pankaj wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15458607/229381).

Comment: To make it clear, when you do `from .m import whatever` in a script you pass as an argument to interpreter, it basically [resolves](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Python/import.c#L1471) to `from __main__.m import whatever`. Which makes it look for `__main__/m.py`.

Comment: "Everyone seems to want to tell you what you should be doing rather than just answering the question." Well, *good*. That's the way getting help writing software *should* be! When I fly in the face of good practice, *I want to know*.

Comment: @Tom I suppose the answer is in the PEP 366 and boils down to something like `if(__name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None): __package__ = "app"`

Comment: @jpmc26 Agreed, but I think it should be a comment then, not an answer.

Comment: How does it answer the question? This just gave links to a couple of references. It is not immediately useful without more jumping over hoops and loops.

Answer (score 165):

Here is the solution which works for me:

I do the relative imports as  `from ..sub2 import mod2`
and then, if I want to run `mod1.py` then I go to the parent directory of `app` and run the module using the python -m switch as  `python -m app.sub1.mod1`.

The real reason why this problem occurs with relative imports, is that relative imports works by taking the `__name__` property of the module. If the module is being directly run, then `__name__` is set to `__main__` and it doesn't contain any information about package structure. And, thats why python complains about the `relative import in non-package` error.

So, by using the -m switch you provide the package structure information to python, through which it can resolve the relative imports successfully.

I have encountered this problem many times while doing relative imports. And, after reading all the previous answers, I was still not able to figure out how to solve it, in a clean way, without needing to put boilerplate code in all files. (Though some of the comments were really helpful, thanks to @ncoghlan and @XiongChiamiov)

Hope this helps someone who is fighting with relative imports problem, because going through PEP is really not fun.

Comment: Best answer IMHO: not only explains why OP had the issue, but also finds a way to solve it *without changing the way his modules do imports*. Afterall, OP's relative imports were fine. The culprit was the lack of access to outer packages when directly running as script, something `-m` was designed to solve.

Comment: Also take note: this answer was 5 years after the question. These features were not available at the time.

Comment: If you want to import a module from the same directory you can do `from . import some_module`.

Comment: This is the answer that helped me and it also helped me condense my thought down to this: **In order to run a Python script which contains relative imports, I must run the script as a module while `$ PWD` is its parent directory like `$ python -m app.main`**. For clarity, `$ python -m <main_directory>.<script_with_relative_imports>`

Answer (score 132):

```
main.py
setup.py
app/ ->
    __init__.py
    package_a/ ->
       __init__.py
       module_a.py
    package_b/ ->
       __init__.py
       module_b.py
```

1. You run `python main.py`.
2. `main.py` does: `import app.package_a.module_a`
3. `module_a.py` does `import app.package_b.module_b`

Alternatively 2 or 3 could use: `from app.package_a import module_a`

That will work as long as you have `app` in your PYTHONPATH. `main.py` could be anywhere then.

So you write a `setup.py` to copy (install) the whole app package and subpackages to the target system's python folders, and `main.py` to target system's script folders.

Comment: Excellent answer. Is there some way to import that way without install the package in PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Suggested additional reading: http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/

Comment: then, one day, need to change name of app to test_app. what would happen? You will need to change all the source codes, import app.package_b.module_b --> test_app.package_b.module_b.
this is absolutely BAD practice... And we should try to use relative import within the package.

Answer (score 55):

"Guido views running scripts within a package as an anti-pattern" (rejected
[PEP-3122](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3122/))

I have spent so much time trying to find a solution, reading related posts here on Stack Overflow and saying to myself "there must be a better way!". Looks like there is not.

Comment: Note: Already mentioned [pep-366](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) (created around the same time as [pep-3122](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3122/)) provides the same capabilities but uses a different backward-compatible implementation i.e., if you want to run a module inside a package as a script *and* use explicit relative imports in it then you could run it using `-m` switch: `python -m app.sub1.mod1` or invoke `app.sub1.mod1.main()` from a top-level script (e.g., generated from setuptools' entry_points defined in setup.py).

Comment: +1 for using setuptools and entry points - it is a proper way to set up scripts that will be run from the outside, in a well-defined location, as opposed to endlessly hacking PYTHONPATH

Comment: Didn't found the definition of 'run' on the peps. For me, it doesn't look like 'running' is the best definition (for the ant pattern) cause at the end the 'interpretation' will link the dependencies and not actually 'run' it at the sense of executing immediately. [Reference 1](http://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663-2016/17_C_InOneLecture.html) and [reference 2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/why-learn-python-an-introduction-to-python/)

Answer (score 48):

This is solved 100%:

- app/

  - main.py
- settings/

  - local_setings.py

Import settings/local_setting.py in app/main.py:

main.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../settings")


try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    print('No Import')
```

Comment: thank you! all ppl were forcing me to run my script differently instead of telling me how to solve it within script. But I had to change the code to use `sys.path.insert(0, "../settings")` and then `from local_settings import *`

Comment: Can you [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35338828/edit) your answer, please? For example, *why* does it work? *How* does it work? What is the gist? *["Explanation is vital for a good answer."_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258474/deal-with-famous-profiles-and-the-possibility-of-fakes/258475#258475)*. (But ***** ***** ***** ***without*** ***** ***** *****  "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Comment: @PeterMortensen it works because it's a hack. Python uses the `path` to look for modules. By default, the directory of where the script is executed from is in the path. This forces the directory that is up one level, called `settings` is inserted into that path.

Like all hacks, this will work in a lot of situations but it's not how imports are intended to work in Python. Other methods are preferred

Answer (score 29):

Explanation of [nosklo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-can-i-do-relative-imports-in-python/465129#465129) with examples:

*Note: all `__init__.py` files are empty.*

```
main.py
app/ ->
    __init__.py
    package_a/ ->
       __init__.py
       fun_a.py
    package_b/ ->
       __init__.py
       fun_b.py
```

#### app/package_a/fun_a.py

```
def print_a():
    print 'This is a function in dir package_a'
```

#### app/package_b/fun_b.py

```
from app.package_a.fun_a import print_a
def print_b():
    print 'This is a function in dir package_b'
    print 'going to call a function in dir package_a'
    print '-'*30
    print_a()
```

#### main.py

```
from app.package_b import fun_b
fun_b.print_b()
```

If you run `python main.py` it returns:

```
This is a function in dir package_b
going to call a function in dir package_a
------------------------------
This is a function in dir package_a
```

- main.py does: `from app.package_b import fun_b`
- fun_b.py does `from app.package_a.fun_a import print_a`

so file in folder `package_b` used file in folder `package_a`, which is what you want. Right??

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is how to do relative imports; this shows only absolute imports.

Answer (score 24):

Use:

```
def import_path(fullpath):
    """ 
    Import a file with full path specification. Allows one to
    import from anywhere, something __import__ does not do. 
    """
    path, filename = os.path.split(fullpath)
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    sys.path.append(path)
    module = __import__(filename)
    reload(module) # Might be out of date
    del sys.path[-1]
    return module
```

I'm using this snippet to import modules from paths.

Comment: I'm using this snippet, combined with the imp module (as explained here [1]) to great effect.  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096216/override-namespace-in-python/1096247#1096247

Comment: Probably, sys.path.append(path) should be replaced with sys.path.insert(0, path), and sys.path[-1] should be replaced with sys.path[0]. Otherwise the function will import the wrong module, if there is already a module with the same name in search path. E.g., if there is "some.py" in current dir, import_path("/imports/some.py") will import the wrong file.

Comment: I agree! Sometimes other relative imports will make precedance. Use sys.path.insert

Comment: How would you replicate the behavior of from x import y (or *)?

Comment: It's not clear, please specify full usage of this script to solve OP problem.

Answer (score 13):

This is unfortunately a sys.path hack, but it works quite well.

I encountered this problem with another layer: I already had a module of the specified name, but it was the wrong module.

what I wanted to do was the following (the module I was working from was module3):

```
mymodule\
   __init__.py
   mymodule1\
      __init__.py
      mymodule1_1
   mymodule2\
      __init__.py
      mymodule2_1


import mymodule.mymodule1.mymodule1_1
```

Note that I have already installed mymodule, but in my installation I do not have "mymodule1"

and I would get an ImportError because it was trying to import from my installed modules.

I tried to do a sys.path.append, and that didn't work.  What did work was a **sys.path.insert**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.path.insert(0, '../..')
```

So kind of a hack, but got it all to work!
So keep in mind, if you want your decision to **override other paths** then you need to use sys.path.insert(0, pathname) to get it to work!  This was a very frustrating sticking point for me, allot of people say to use the "append" function to sys.path, but that doesn't work if you already have a module defined (I find it very strange behavior)

Comment: `sys.path.append('../')` works fine for me (Python 3.5.2)

Comment: I think this is fine since it localizes the hack to the executable and doesn't affect other modules which may depend on your packages.

Answer (score 10):

Let me just put this here for my own reference. I know that it is not good Python code, but I needed a script for a project I was working on and I wanted to put the script in a `scripts` directory.

```
import os.path
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))
```

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports. You could do

```
from .mod1 import stuff
```

Comment: Except one can't do relative imports from the '__main__' module as the  answer from John B. states

Answer (score 8):

As [EvgeniSergeev says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-can-i-do-relative-imports-in-python#comment37181131_72852) in the comments to the OP, you can import code from a `.py` file at an arbitrary location with:

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

This is taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/2071807).

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is how to use relative imports correctly, not "please just enable me to import the file".

Answer (score 2):

From [Python doc](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports),

> In Python 2.5, you can switch import‘s behaviour to absolute imports using a `from __future__ import absolute_import` directive. This absolute- import behaviour will become the default in a future version (probably Python 2.7). Once absolute imports are the default, `import string` will always find the standard library’s version. It’s suggested that users should begin using absolute imports as much as possible, so it’s preferable to begin writing `from pkg import string` in your code

Answer (score 2):

On top of what [John B said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-can-i-do-relative-imports-in-python/73149#73149), it seems like setting the `__package__` variable should help, instead of changing `__main__` which could screw up other things. But as far as I could test, it doesn't completely work as it should.

I have the same problem and neither [PEP 328](https://peps.python.org/pep-0328/) nor [PEP 366](https://peps.python.org/pep-0366/) solve the problem completely, as both, by the end of the day, need the head of the package to be included in `sys.path`, as far as I could understand.

Answer (score 1):

I found it's easier to set the "PYTHONPATH" environment variable to the top folder:

```
bash$ export PYTHONPATH=/PATH/TO/APP
```

Then:

```
import sub1.func1
# ...more imports
```

Of course, PYTHONPATH is "global", but it didn't raise trouble for me yet.

Comment: This is essentially how `virtualenv` lets you manage your import statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the module’s path to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/your/module/"
```

Comment: This is roughly the same as manipulating `sys.path`, since `sys.path` gets initialized from `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @Joril That's correct but `sys.path` needs to be hardcoded in the source code in contrast to `PYTHONPATH` which is an environment variable and can be exported.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way to do it is to append the current directory to the PATH at runtime as follows:

```
import pathlib   
import sys
sys.path.append(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve())
import file_to_import  # the actual intended import
```

In contrast to another solution for this question this uses `pathlib` instead of `os.path`.

Answer (score -2):

What a debate!

I am a relative newcomer to Python (but years of programming experience, and dislike of [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)) and am a relative layperson when it comes to the dark art of [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) setup, but I know what I (think I) need to get my little experimental projects working at home.

Here is my summary of what the situation seems to be.

If I use the -m 'module' approach, I need to:

1. dot it all together;
2. run it from a parent folder;
3. lose the '.py';
4. create an empty (!) `__init__.py` file in every subfolder.

How does that work in a [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) environment, where I have aliased my scripts directory, and want to run a script directly as */dirAlias/cgi_script.py*??

Why is amending *sys.path* a hack?  The [Python documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) states: *"A program is free to modify this list for its own purposes."* If it works, it works, right?  The bean counters in Accounts don't care how it works.

I *just* want to go up one level and down into a 'modules' directory:

```
.../py
      /cgi
      /build
      /modules
```

So my 'modules' can be imported from either the CGI world or the server world.

I've tried the `-m`/modules approach but I think I prefer the following (and am not confused how to run it in CGI space):

1. Create `XX_pathsetup.py` in the */path/to/python/Lib* directory (or any other directory in the default *sys.path* list).  'XX' is some identifier that declares an intent to set up my path according to the rules in the file.
2. In any script that wants to be able to import from the 'modules' directory in above directory config, simply `import XX_pathsetup.py`.

And here's my really simple *XX_pathsetup.py* file:

```
import sys, os
pypath = sys.path[0].rsplit(os.sep, 1)[0]
sys.path.insert(0, pypath + os.sep + 'modules')
```

It is *not* a 'hack', IMHO. It is one small file to put in the Python 'Lib' directory and one import statement which declares intent to modify the path search order.

Comment: This answer is wrong on many levels. `__init__.py` files have not been required for marking packages since Python 3.3 and they are intended for a completely orthogonal purpose. They are never required to be empty; it's just less work to make an empty file than a non-empty one. Aside from that, please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum** and answers are expected to get directly to the point without talking about personal experiences or related problems you have tried to solve (please read [answer]). Finally, why are you working directly with CGI in 2023?